# Accessing stacked data structures with HTML::Template::Compiled

Tags: perl

To display a task dashboard on the web I take information from a file with Perl, store that in a stacked hash and send it to [`HTML::Template::Compiled`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Template::Compiled).

There I can only access the key of the hash but no further data.

Here is what I wrote in Perl

```
my $template = HTML::Template::Compiled->new(
  filename               => '../templates/task_dashboard.tmpl',
  case_sensitive         => 1,
  search_path_on_include => 1,
  loop_context_vars      => 1,
  use_query              => 0,
  default_escape         => 'HTML',
);
$template->param(
  TIME      => $time,
  VERSION   => $version,
  REPORTDAT => $reportdat,
  INFOS     => \%information,
);
print $template->output();
```

The hash `%information` looks like this:

```
%informmation{key} = ($RefToArrayOfHashes1, $RefToArrayOfHashes2, $Skalar1, $Skalar2);
```

Within `HTML::Template::Compiled` I want to loop through the hash `%information` and subsequently through its content (like `Data::Dumper`).

I wrote this in the template file:

```
<%each INFOS %>
  <h2><%=__key__ %></h2>
  <table>
    ...loop through RefToArrayOfHashes1
  </table>
  <table>
    ...loop through RefToArrayOfHashes2
  </table>
  <p>Skalar1, Skalar2</p>
<%/each %>
```

To access the keys of `%information` is not a problem, but I don't know how to access the lower levels of the data structure.

I read some things about to use Dot but still don't get how to do it.

Can anybody help me by giving an example?